# Как в PHP найти и забрать данные в файле.TXT после запятой

Tags: php

*Например такая строка:*
**7854, mail@mail.com**

У меня получается только саму строку находить или значение. Но не конкретный параметр в строке.

Есть только такое решение пока

```
<?php  
  $st_strpos = "114.16"; //слово или фразу, которую нужно найти в файле
    $st_search = "yandex.txt"; //название файла, в котором нужно найти (если нужно, то еще пропишите путь к файлу)
    echo "<br>" . "Результат поиска в файле $st_search: <br>";
    if (strpos(file_get_contents("$st_search"), "$st_strpos")) echo "Есть такое слово"; else echo "Нет такого слова";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через explode сделать

```
$str = '12312 ,13iut13';
$txt = trim(explode(',', $str)[1]);
```

Это упрощённая версия, нужно понимать, что если запятой не будет, то и индекса 1 тоже не будет

Comment: ну так `?? null` его

Comment: Просто неизвестно какое поведение требуется в итоге. Так что оставлю на усмотрение

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$lines = @file("/test"); # открываем как массив, @ - подавление ошибки открытия
if ($lines !== false) { # если открыли успешно
    foreach ($lines as $line) { # для каждой строки
        if (strpos($line, ", ") === false) continue; # если в строке есть разделитель ", "
        list($id, $mail) = explode($line, ", ", 2); # Делим, и получаем id, mail 
        var_dump($id, $mail); # Делаем какие-то действия с id и mail
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй добавлю для понимания:

```
<?php
$myString = "7854, mail@mail.com";
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
foreach($myArray as $my_Array){
    echo $my_Array.'<br>';  

}
```

А дальше с 1-м параметром или N можно делать что надо.